# Search input is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m working on live search but I didn´t understand where I did mistake when I enter any key images became hidden filter its not working. I want show the searched value as a card view which I made in my `html` file. I´m working almost 1 day but I didnt get the answer as I want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.myImg').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('alt', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });
    $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.myImg').each(function() {
            if ($(this).filter('[alt *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
html,body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
}
 #stripe img{
     margin-bottom: 15px;
}
 h1{
     color: white;
     font-size: 2em;
     font-family: 'Butcherman', cursive;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 img + h1{
     display: inline-block;
}
 #stripe{
     position: relative;
     background: #404040;
     height: 70px;
     text-align: center;
     right: 0;
}
 .card {
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
}
 .card:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
 h4{
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 15px;
}
 #sec2{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     top: 30px;
}
 .live-search-box {
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     padding: 1em;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 1px solid #3498db;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <title>test video</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Butcherman&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="stripe">
      <img src="logo/mask.png">
      <h1>My Website</h1>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="live-search-box" placeholder="search here" />
   <section id="sec2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="John Doe" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>John Doe</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Steve John" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Steve John</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="John Cenna" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>John Cenna</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Mark William" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Mark William</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="William Wordssmith" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>William Wordssmith</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Jason Wathson" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Jason Wathson</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Jimmy Coogan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Jimmy Coogan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Mark Zuckerberg" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Mark Zuckerberg</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Sharukh Khan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Sharukh Khan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Hrithik Roshan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Hrithik Roshan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Salman Khan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Salman Khan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Shahid Kapoor" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Shahid Kapoor</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Dibendu Mondal" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Dibendu Mondal</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Sudip Barik" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Sudip Barik</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Masum Abdulla" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Masum Abdulla</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Debabrata Maji" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Debabrata Maji</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console? If there is no error, do you search for full names? The filter is case sensitive, maybe you will not find what you want, because in JS you do a toLower on the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some modifications:

- to avoid altering the `alt` attribute
- to select the `col-*` containing the image. It can be improved.
- to use the parameters passed to the function by `each`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {

    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('.myImg').each(function(idx, item) {
        var alt = $(item).attr("alt").toLowerCase();

        if (alt.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0 ||searchTerm.length < 1) {
            $(item).parent().parent().show();
        } else {
            $(item).parent().parent().hide();
        }

      });

  });

});
```

```css
html,body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
}
 #stripe img{
     margin-bottom: 15px;
}
 h1{
     color: white;
     font-size: 2em;
     font-family: 'Butcherman', cursive;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 img + h1{
     display: inline-block;
}
 #stripe{
     position: relative;
     background: #404040;
     height: 70px;
     text-align: center;
     right: 0;
}
 .card {
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     transition: 0.3s;
}
 .card:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
 h4{
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 15px;
}
 #sec2{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     top: 30px;
}
 .live-search-box {
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     padding: 1em;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border: 1px solid #3498db;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <title>test video</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Butcherman&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="stripe">
      <img src="logo/mask.png">
      <h1>My Website</h1>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="live-search-box" placeholder="search here" />
   <section id="sec2">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="John Doe" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>John Doe</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Steve John" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Steve John</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="John Cenna" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>John Cenna</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Mark William" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Mark William</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="William Wordssmith" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>William Wordssmith</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Jason Wathson" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Jason Wathson</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Jimmy Coogan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Jimmy Coogan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Mark Zuckerberg" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Mark Zuckerberg</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Sharukh Khan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Sharukh Khan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Hrithik Roshan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Hrithik Roshan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Salman Khan" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Salman Khan</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Shahid Kapoor" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Shahid Kapoor</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Dibendu Mondal" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Dibendu Mondal</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Sudip Barik" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Sudip Barik</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Masum Abdulla" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Masum Abdulla</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                  <div class="card thumbnail">
                     <img class="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/831993825635745796/HnVmB0-k_400x400.jpg" alt="Debabrata Maji" style="width:100%">
                     <h4>Debabrata Maji</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Can u help little more as hotstar search bar shows the list when we entering key the list appears that design was awesome that i m also want my search bar shows that list plz can u help me for this with html css and jquery

Comment: @narayanmaity You should open a new question for this new need.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this code. This is working for code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.myImg').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('alt', $(this).next().text().toLowerCase());
    });

    $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function () {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.myImg').each(function () {
            if ($(this).filter('[alt *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 
                     || searchTerm.length < 1) {
                $(this).parent().parent().show();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its working but minor problem if i search the last one which is  debabrata maji the card didnt come to the first poistion the card shows in the forth column not the first column

Comment: thanks @Ankit parmar it works but plz make that card will show the first column

Comment: I have updated two lines
 $(this).parent().parent().show();
$(this).parent().parent().hide();

Comment: Hi Ankit! I have slightly edited your answer to fix the code formatting. Nevertheless, please also add more context to your answer, particularly motivating / reasoning your changes to the original code snippet provided in the question. This would help further users understand the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Current code produces `$(...).attr(...).text is not a function`

Change

```
$(this).attr('alt', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
```

to

```
$(this).attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt').toLowerCase());
```